# SQL SPARK - Creating queries with 2 dataframes

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes loaded with the following structure.

My first dataframe which is called dfBooks.

```
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      ISBN|          Book-Title|         Book-Author|Year-Of-Publication|           Publisher|         Image-URL-S|         Image-URL-M|         Image-URL-L|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|0195153448| Classical Mythology|  Mark P. O. Morford|               2002|Oxford University...|http://images.ama...|http://images.ama...|http://images.ama...|
|0002005018|        Clara Callan|Richard Bruce Wright|               2001|HarperFlamingo Ca...|http://images.ama...|http://images.ama...|http://images.ama...|
```

And my second one which is called dfBooks_Rating.

```
+-------+----------+-----------+
|User-ID|      ISBN|Book-Rating|
+-------+----------+-----------+
| 276725|034545104X|          0|
| 276726|0155061224|          5|
| 276727|0446520802|          0|
| 276729|052165615X|          3|
| 276729|0521795028|          6|
| 276733|2080674722|          0|
| 276736|3257224281|          8|
| 276737|0600570967|          6|
| 276744|038550120X|          7|
| 276745| 342310538|         10|
| 276746|0425115801|          0|
| 276746|0449006522|          0|
| 276746|0553561618|          0|
| 276746|055356451X|          0|
| 276746|0786013990|          0|
| 276746|0786014512|          0|
| 276747|0060517794|          9|
| 276747|0451192001|          0|
| 276747|0609801279|          0|
| 276747|0671537458|          9|
+-------+----------+-----------+
```

QUESTION, **OBTAIN MAX RATE FOR EACH PUBLISHER**

My idea to calculate it was using groupBy function to group each dataframe by **ISBN**, but I think it should be a better method for this purpose.

Here is my code for loading my dfs.

```
def crearDataFrame(nombre_fichero):
    df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ";").load(nombre_fichero)
    return df
```

Dataframe loading:

```
dfUser = crearDataFrame("BX-Users.csv")
dfBooks = crearDataFrame("BX-Book.csv")
```

My idea for grouping each one to create my correct query.

```
df_ = dfUser.join(dfBooks, dfUser.ISBN == dfBooks.ISBN, 'inner').show()
```

**Do you know if it's posible to create a query using both df at the same time?**

Thanks you all.

Comment: What's your question?  Why don't you want to use `groupBy` for aggregation?

Comment: I just updated my question, I had a mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This should compute the max rating for each publisher.

```
dfBooks
    .select("ISBN", "Publisher")
    .join(dfBooks_Rating, Seq("ISBN"))
    .groupBy("Publisher")
    .agg(max($"Book-Rating") as "maxRating")
    .show
```